# How can I buy advance tickets for Anne Frank House?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, bookings, amsterdam

At this writing (20 July) the earliest dates I can find for advance [tickets](http://www.annefrank.org/en/Museum/Practical-information/Online-ticket-sales/) to the Anne Frank House in Amsterdam are in September. *Do they really sell out that far in advance?* Or is this some glitch and more will be posted. (I realize that the site says "if possible" more are released one week in advance, but there are none for the upcoming week.)

If not, any suggestions on day of week and time of day to minimize the wait?

Comment: We don't get enough follow-up comments. We went in the early evening, and the wait was 1:45. As indicated in the answers, the Museum Card was accepted for admission but did not have a separate queue. (At the Van Gogh Museum the cardholders queue separately. We waited 0:20; I estimate the regular queue was double.)

Comment: One suggestion: keep trying the ticket website obsessively. When I went last fall, they periodically posted more tickets a few days in advance. I spent a few days reloading the ticket calendar page on my phone and managed to grab one. An advance ticket means you can go in the side door directly, which saved hours of waiting in a long hot line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to their website, they only release some tickets online, so "Sold Out" doesn't actually mean you can't go, only that the tickets released online have been sold out.

From the [website](http://www.annefrank.org/en/Museum/Practical-information/Online-ticket-sales/) they suggest their tickets may be bought out by scalpers:

> Resellers of our entrance tickets are active on the internet. They buy
> up our entrance tickets online, and attempt to sell them at a large
> profit, often for double the price. This is not permitted. Do not buy
> tickets from these organisations; you may be refused entry.

... and in the [FAQ section](http://www.annefrank.org/en/Museum/Practical-information/Frequently-asked-questions/Online-ticket-sales/#40)...

> **I want to make a timed reservation using the online reservation system
> on the website, but I see that very few times are left available. Is
> the service really fully booked, or is there another way to make a
> reservation?**  On the website you can see exactly what times are still
> available. If you still want to come at a particular time for which no
> more online tickets are available, then you can always buy tickets at
> the Anne Frank House entry desk. However, you may have to wait in the
> queue.

The place is almost always busy as noted by many reviews online and from my own experience as well.

Here are some tips (some are common sense):

- Summer months (especially July-August) will be a lot busier than other times of the year. Go in winter when people are less inclined to queue outside.
- Weekends will be busier than weekdays.
- Check the [Opening Times](http://www.annefrank.org/en/Museum/Practical-information/Opening-hours-prices-and-location1/) and arrive a half-hour before opening (or earlier). The wait times later in the day can reach over 3 hours (in peak periods).
- Go in the evenings (after 5 or 6pm) when the queues are shorter.  This won't work in Summer however.
- Some third parties may sell "general entrance tickets" but these won't let you skip the line, I think you need to exchange these at the ticket counter
- When purchasing tickets at the counter, they must be used then, so you can't purchase them for later in the day or another day
- You could try to join organised tours that claim they can [skip the line](http://www.getyourguide.com/amsterdam-l36/amsterdam-world-war-ii-tour-and-anne-frank-house-t52763/).
- If you do manage to get a ticket online, this allows entry at a specific time on a particular day, and you won't have to wait in line, there is a separate entrance.

Finally if you do see a line, [how long is the wait?](http://www.eurocheapo.com/blog/amsterdam-tip-avoiding-lines-at-anne-frank-house.html)

> 5. Estimating the wait
>
> How can you gauge your time? If the line is an L shape, ending just
> along the Westerkerk, that’s about an hour. If the line is an L shape
> but ends past the Westerkerk and at the Keizergracht canal, that’s two
> hours. If the line is a Z and has now turned at the Keizergracht canal
> and is running behind the Westerkerk, that’s three hours. Any longer,
> well, you do the math.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that it is still necessary to wait if you have a Museumkaart?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Not necessarily. I haven't been to the Anne Frank House so I can't positively confirm it's the same there but at the Rijksmuseum or the Mauritshuis you walk directly to the entrance where they scan the card itself with their machine. You don't need to wait at the desk to get an actual ticket (which is where the queue usually is). IIRC, I also bypassed the queue at the Van Gogh museum a few years ago. Even though I did need a ticket, there was a special lane for groups, friends of the museum, etc. and you could use that one with a museumkaart.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Actually, you do need to wait at the Anne Frank House, just found this [on the website](http://www.annefrank.org/nl/Museum/Praktische-informatie/Tijden-prijzen-en-locatie1/) : “Houders van een Museumkaart, Stadspas en CJP dienen in de rij aan te sluiten of kunnen online reserveren met hun kaart.” (it's only in the Dutch version). It means you have to wait in the queue but you can also reserve online with your museumkaart.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus yes you must wait in line even with the Museumkaart, as Relaxed mentioned you can use the card to purchase a ticket online and avoid the queues, the cost will only be €0,50. Take a look at the info on this TripAdvisor forum http://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/ShowTopic-g188590-i60-k5602704-Anne_Frank_House_and_the_Museumkaart_an_explanation-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html

Comment: Thank you, @Relaxed. We will certainly buy Museumkaarts as our style of travel is heavy on museums, and upon reading that I could get timed tickets at the Anne Frank House for 50 (Euro) cents each even before having the cards in hand, I went over to their website, and ten minutes later, I was posting this question!